# How to get and set a global object in Java servlet context

Tags: java, servlets, quartz-scheduler

I wonder if anyone can advise: I have a scenario where a scheduled job being run by Quartz will update an arraylist of objects every hour.

But I need this arraylist of objects to be visible to all sessions created by Tomcat. So what I'm thinking is that I write this object somewhere every hour from the Quartz job that runs so that each session can access it.

Can anyone say how best this may be achieved? I was wondering about the object being written to servlet context from the Quartz job? The alternative is having each session populate the arraylist of objects from a database table.

Thanks

Mr Morgan.

Comment: There is a useful discussion of this challenge in this other SOF post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276041/retrieve-servletcontext-reference-in-quartz-scheduler

Comment: Global Application Context like the one from Spring?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I would store the list in the `ServletContext` as an application-scoped attribute.  Pulling the data from a database instead is probably less efficient, since you're only updating the list every hour.  Creating a `ServletContextListener` might be necessary in order to give the Quartz task a reference to the `ServletContext` object.  The `ServletContext` can only be retrieved from JavaEE-related classes like Servlets and Listeners.

EDIT:
In the ServletContextListener, when you create the job, you can pass the list into the job by adding it to a JobDataMap.

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    //add to ServletContext
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("list", list);

    JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
    map.put("list", list);
    JobDetail job = new JobDetail(..., MyJob.class);
    job.setJobDataMap(map);
    //execute job
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){}
}

//Quartz job
public class MyJob implements Job{
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context){
    ArrayList list = (ArrayList)context.getMergedJobDataMap().get("list");
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that I have a listener that has a method in it to populate the object; this listener runs when the context is initialised and populates the object. The Quartz job can then get at the object via the listener when it runs every hour?

Comment: Looking at a comment from another answer, it looks like you already have a ServletContextListener that starts the Quartz task?  What you can do is create the list in the listener, then add the list as an attribute to the ServletContext, then pass that same list to the task.  You can then access the list anywhere in your web application by calling `ServletContext#getAttribute()`.  For example, in a servlet, you'd call `(ArrayList)getServletContext().getAttribute("list")`.  Make sure you properly synchronize your list so that you're not reading/writing to it as the same time.

Comment: This sounds good but with one exception. I'm not sure if 'then pass that same list to the task' is possible given the way in which the jobs are submitted by Quartz's ScheduleController.

Comment: You just have to somehow make sure that the ServletContext and the Quartz task both have a reference to the same ArrayList object that you want to use in your web application.  If the ArrayList is created in the task, maybe you could pass the task a reference to the ServletContext object and make the task add the list to the ServletContext.

Comment: What I've just tried is creating a method in the ServletContextListener which returns an integer. When the Quartz job runs, it creates an instance of the ServletContextListener and calls the method. It seems to work but needs testing. Replacing the integer with an arraylist and having the ServletContextListener's method repopulate the list, and synchronising this, may solve the problem.

Comment: You should never create a new instance of a listener.  Only the Container should do that.  What does to the code for your Quartz job look like? (sorry, I'm not familiar with Quartz)  Is the job a class that extends some Quartz class?  If so, you can just create a setter method in the job class which gives the job a reference to the list.  Something like: `ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); QuartzJob job = new QuartzJob(); job.setList(list); servletContext.setAttribute("list", list);`

Comment: With Quartz, the jobs are submitted by defining the job and a trigger, and then making a call to a method called: scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, ct); where jd is the job and ct is a cron trigger. The jobs submitted implement an interface of quartz's called Job via a method called execute.

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/examples/Example3.html gives a good few examples.

Comment: What if you put the ArrayList in a `JobDataMap`?  Then, you could access the JobDataMap from the JobExecutionContext in the `execute()` method and then get the list.

Comment: I never saw this before. Converting the arraylist to a map could allow the map to be built up within the job. But doesn't it leave the problem of setting the list / map to ServletContext?

Comment: You don't need to convert anything to a map.  (1) Create the ArrayList in the listener.  (2) Add the list to the ServletContext.  (3) Add the list to a new JobDataMap object. (4) Add that JobDataMap object to the JobDetail object. `servletContext.setAttribute("list", list); JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap(); map.put("list", list); JobDetail jd = ...; jd.setJobDataMap(map);`

Comment: Then, access the list from the job class' `execute()` method.  `ArrayList list = (ArrayList)context.getMergedJobDataMap().get("list");`

Comment: I follow you but the problem is that the arraylist needs to be updated by the job. and servlet context is not accessible from the job itself.

Comment: Right, the list gets added to the ServletContext in the ServletContextListener.  Both the ServletContext and the job will have a reference to the same list object.  So when the job updates the list, the list in the ServletContext will also be updated.

Comment: So updates to the JobMap within the job will appear in the list object by virtue of passing by reference. I will try this tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment, time constraints dictate that I use database table for storage. But I will replace this later with a SessionListener which populates my arraylist. Any method needing to access the arraylist can then read it via a static method in the Listener's class. But I'd still like to use ServletContext.

Comment: See the edits to my answer for a code sample...I don't see how this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some caching solution, like [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) to store you values, and update them every hour. It will handle concurrency issues. The cache object itself can be stored in the `ServletContext`

A good way to write to the `ServletContext` from the Quartz job is to register listeners to your job that get notified about the changed value. So for example:

```
public class JobListener {
    public void updateValue(Object newValue);
}

public class ServletContextCacheJobListener implements JobListener {
     private ServletContext ctx;
     public ServletContextJobListener(ServletContext ctx) {
         this.ctx = ctx;
     }

     public void updateValue(Object newValue) {
          Cache cache = (Cache) ctx.getAttribute("cache");
          cache.update("yourKey", newValue);
     }
}
```

Your Job will have a `List<JobListener>` and when you schedule the job, you instantiate the concrete listener and add it to the job.

Comment: Not sure I understand quite where you're coming from. Can you clarify? Are you saying that my Quartz job should have a list of JobListener or ServletContextCacheJobListener? If the latter, presumably I would then set the list one element at a time?

Comment: Read about the Observer (listener) pattern. And `ServletContextCacheJobListener` is a `JobListener` because it implements it. So there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use static fields they will be visible to all classes loaded by the same class loader. I think that at least the servlets of one app should end up qualifying. However, this is admittedly dirty.

An object that is defined and guaranteed to be (more) global is the [ServletContext](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/ServletContext.shtml). This is shared between all servlets forming part of one application, i.e. loaded from the same `web.xml`. There are `put` and `get` calls for ServletContext that allow you treat it essentially as a Map.

Beyond that, you'll need to find classes common to all Web apps inside one Tomcat server. Tomcat does a lot of footwork with loaders, and I think different Web apps will have distinct loaders. You can get around this by writing a class of your own and placing that class in Tomcat's `common` or `shared` directories. If I understand [this description](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/class-loader-howto.html) correctly, those classes will be made available, ONCE, to all Web apps.

Finally, beyond the confines of a single Tomcat server, you'll need some TCP/IP based mechanism for communicating between JVMs. But as I understood your question, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: But can you access ServletContext outside of a servlet? The Quartz job i mention is one that implments an interface of theirs. I am prepared to use a class with statics though.

Comment: Hmm. Is this Quartz job running as a servlet or filter inside Tomcat? If so, yes. If it's being fired up in an external JVM it will have trouble looking into Tomcat's brain. Looking at [this Quartz doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler.html), it looks like Quartz will be inside your app, though, and all should be well.

Comment: At least Quartz gets access to your ServletContext (in both of the scenarios described). I'd hope Quartz then has the good sense to make that context accessible to its API users as well.

Comment: I think the Quartz job runs inside Tomcat because a ServletContextListener initiates a Quartz ScheduleController which 'submits' the job in question.

Comment: Yep, I'm glad to see you're implementing one of the recommended scenarios. Do I have to go digging in the Quartz docs now? I'll be back...

Comment: Hmm, the doc on Quartz under a servlet environment are not very forthcoming. I'm essentially down to guessing, based on the Quartz API. Ah... your work unit, the Job, implements the `Job` interface. It gets a `JobExecutionContext`. Chances are, you can use that context's `put` and `get` methods to communicate arbitrary data via job instances in the container. Try it!

Comment: Assuming I set it up correctly, it failed. I ran a job to populate a variable in the Quartz jobExecutionContext, and used a servlet to access the variable from ServletContext after. But the variable was null.

Comment: Oops... I'd missed that you want to access the values from an activity that isn't a Quartz job. No, the execution context and the servlet context are not the same thing. I think you should bite the bullet and use the static var in `/shared`.