# Start & Stop a ScheduledExecutorService in Java EE environment using servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduledexecutorservice, start-stop-daemon

We have a requirement where in we need to monitor remote JVM details via JMX using a simple servlet application. So things done till now in a standalone application is

1) Creat a JMX connector & get the Memory data --> done
2) We need to constantly monitor & get the records 
(2.1 > which can be considered as scheduled task at constant delay & insert the records into DB Or 2.2> does the JMX gives the history if yes which MBean to access for the info?).

Here I am planning to use an interface to register the domain , followed to it. Have start & stop button from JSP. The functionality been when we click start the system will run the scheduler (ScheduledExecutorService  ) & capture the records at background to give the history. When the uses clicks stop the scheduler has to stop the background process.  The question is how can we control & get the object of a scheduler ?

1) In other words how can we start & stop a ScheduledExecutorService via servlets ? start a thread from one servlet & stop a thread from another servlet  for a particular task ?

2) What if we have a clustered/load balanced environment ?

Currently am thinking of adding each ScheduledExecutorService  into HashMap , key been the task object & value been the ScheduledExecutorService  using SingleTon desgin pattern. Is there any default approach. The loop whole with SingleTon is in clustered/load balanced environment we may not be able to get the appropriate update objects.

Looking forward for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If on java ee 7, try using the [`javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html)

Then you can do a resource injection and start the task with code similiar to below.

```
@Resource
ManagedScheduledExecutorService mses;

public void startTask() {
    mses.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 10, 10, SECONDS);
}
```

In Java EE 6 you could have a servlet create/remove using the [timerservice](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#giqlt) API

Comment: +1, I am using Java 6. Few question, 1)Wrt to the above example of assuming runnable is a task started from servlet A, How will Servlet B can stop runnable task itself & not the other task ? As if I am not wrong servlets will be statless & we are not sharing any objects.       2) wrt to TimeService API you are suggesting me to create a EJB, maintain statefull & work around it ?

Comment: No, I would create timers that can be identified by their names. I'll add an example for how I think it could work. But prop not today.

Comment: above was on 2). On 1) i would use shutdownNow() to fetch all tasks, remove the tasks that should be stoped and then reschedule the rest. I will try to add more complete example. But no time today

Comment: +1. TY for your suggestion in-between while you help me to understand by example, I will try the homework based on suggestion & try to put the real scenario. If I am able to get some success will share it here. So it may help others too if they find something similar situation

Comment: I am running an application across several (ec2) instances (behind a load balancer). I still don’t quite see how a ManagedScheduledExecutorService will allow me to schedule tasks across the instances. Can you elaborate? Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

## `ServletContext`

A [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) represents your entire web app as running in the Servlet container. The context is established before the first HTTP request is processed by the servlet, as promised by the [Servlet spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340). While a [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) represents each user’s work session (technically, a thread through your servlet code), a `ServletContext` represents the scope across all those users.

To hook into the set-up and tear-down of the servlet context, implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Tip: Auto-deploy your listener by marking it with [`@WebListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation. That interface requires a pair of methods, each called when your web app is being set-up before the first Servlet request is handled and when your web app is being torn-down.

Tip: That tear-down method is a good place to shut down your `ScheduledExecutorService`. The threads associated with your executor service may survive after your web app ends. You likely do not want that to happen.

See this Question: [How to get and set a global object in Java servlet context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3215988/642706)

See also [this nice summary of Servlet scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106909/642706) by BalusC.

### Fetch the servlet context

You can access the current servlet’s `ServletContext` by first accessing its [`ServletConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html).

```
// … in your Servlet, such as its request handler methods like `doGet` …
ServletContext sc = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext() ;
```

And how about in a `ServletContextListener`, how do we access the servlet context? When either of the two methods on the listener is called, a [ServletContextEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent.html) is passed. From there call [`ServletContextEvent::getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent.html#getServletContext--).

### Store objects as ”attributes” on servlet context

So where to store your web app’s global variables such as your [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)? The servlet context has a built in map of `String` to [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). These are called “attributes”. Call [`setAttribute( String , Object )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) to store an attribute mapping. So make up a name for your `ScheduledExecutorService` to use a key into this map.

```
ScheduledExecutorService sec = … ; // Instantiated somewhere in your code. 
…
String key = "myScheduledExecutorServiceForXYZ" ;
sc.setAttribute( key , sec );  // Storing the executor service as a generic `Object` for use later.
```

Later you can fetch your `ScheduledExecutorService` in the same manner. You will need to cast from `Object` to the known class, in this case `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
Object o = sc.getAttribute( key ); // Fetch the `ScheduledExecutorService` from the servlet context’s built-in map of attributes.

// Cast to known class. If in doubt, test first with [`instanceOf`][11].
ScheduledExecutorService sec = ( ScheduledExecutorService ) o ;
```

You can ask for a list of all stored attribute names by calling [`ServletContext::getAttributeNames`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttributeNames--).

### Diagram of scope

Here is a diagram of mine to get an idea of the hierarchy of scope in a Servlet environment. Note how each layer of scope has its set of attributes, its own map of `String` to `Object`. As you go down the diagram, each set of attributes has a shorter lifespan.

[image]