# How is a Tomcat class used in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, connection-pooling

I am interested in understanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15632353/2031150) code, but I am not sure how to get IntelliJ to be able to use Tomcat's PoolProperties.  If it were an external library such as the Connector/J or a JSTL library, I might be able to figure it out, but since a web program is already using Tomcat, I am not sure.  Should I be using the Project Structure menu to add a Tomcat library?

Comment: try using Maven to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the project's *dependency management* tool you're using. If it's `Maven` or `Gradle`, you just need to register the dependency `Tomcat JDBC`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Or for `Gradle`

```
implementation 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:9.0.16'
```

Remember to pick a version which is compatible with the `Tomcat` web server version you're using.
Look at [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc).

If the process of adding dependencies is manual, you need to add the `JAR` file via the *IDEA Module* settings. You'd also need to manually copy that `JAR` to the build artifact (e.g. the `WAR` file), under the appropriate directory.

Comment: You can also add dependency for source code. that you enable you to step into tomcat code base.

Comment: @ringadingding that module might not be part of a standard Tomcat installation.