# How to access a running servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, cron, quartz-scheduler, servlet-filters

I will be creating a `ServletFilter` that will alter the way HTTP Requests are processed.

The `ServletFilter` will make those decisions based on the state of the data in the database.

I would rather not have a database hit happen every time the `ServletFilter` is invoked.

The webapp already has `quartz` implemented, so hitting the database at a predetermined time is not a problem.

My question is, *how can I contact the `ServeltFilter` at these timed intervals to give it a new set of saved information until the next timed interval?*

---

**Update:**
There is useful discussion in this SOF post about getting a ServletContext into a Quartz job.
[How to get and set a global object in Java servlet context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215988/how-to-get-and-set-a-global-object-in-java-servlet-context)

Comment: Ew. Wrong way 'round; should be a service both the filter and servlet can call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to find the Filter to tell it,
have the Filter look the information up by querying a service somewhere (e.g. stored in the `ServletContext`), or just have the service store the information in the `ServletContext`.

Comment: Very cool!  That is a better way of looking at it, and less hassle.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Yes *you can, but though I would not recommend it*, since your update functionality should not be located there but in a class responsible for that task, this improves cohesion.

- If you'd like to know how to get the filter, take a look at this method in the javadoc.

  [ServletContext.getFilterRegistration()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getFilterRegistration%28java.lang.String%29)
- The Servlet context instance can be obtained by calling this method:

  [ServletContext.getContext("path")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29)

Hope you find this helpful.