# Obtain the formbean updated by other session in struts 1.x

Tags: java, struts-1

In struts 1.x is that allowed for two browser (in this case two sessions) operate on the same `actionForm` one after another and  in the action class get the updated `actionForm` updated by another session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not a behavior with struts but a behavior with all Web Applications.
Any value stored in session is available to only the same browser/user albeit across multiple requests.

If you do have a requirement to share values across session then you will have to look at alternate options like:

1. Storing in DB
2. Using a Singleton to share the data
3. Share the data through ServletContext. For more info [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215988/how-to-get-and-set-a-global-object-in-java-servlet-context)
4. Have a static value in your class. This will allow you to share objects across session and requests. Be careful with threading though.